# webpage zoom not working in FF

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

I am trying to create a website for accessibility, where in to satisfy one of the guidelines "Visible Text" according to WCAG 2.0, I am providing a function with two buttons. Clicking on "SmallFont" link, the page would get smaller and smaller and there by clicking on "BigFont" link, the page would get bigger and bigger, so that the user can use it however required.

Following what I have done to implement the same.:

HTML:

```
<div id="fontAlter"> <a class="fontMinus" href="#">A</a>
<a class="fontPlus" href="#">A</a></div>
<div>Page Zoom</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
   font-size: 75%;
}
.fontPlus {
   font-size:1.63em;
}
```

JS:

```
var defaultZoom = 100;
// Increase Font Size
$(".fontPlus").click(function () {
var newZoom = defaultZoom + 10;
if (newZoom < 200) {
    $('html').css('zoom', newZoom + '%');
    defaultZoom = newZoom;
 }
});
// Decrease Font Size
$(".fontMinus").click(function () {
var newZoom = defaultZoom - 10;
if (newZoom > 75) {
    $('html').css('zoom', newZoom + '%');
    defaultZoom = newZoom;
}
```

This is working with chrome, however not able to create fiddle to demo this. In my application, it is working

Now all I want is to work in FF(Firefox)

Any help is appreciate!

Comment: How will the page 'get bigger' or 'get smaller', don't  you mean you're changing the size of the text?

Comment: Yes Everything in the page is changing. This works like the zoom in chrome

Comment: But changing text size isn't the same as browser zooming. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes yes, understood your point. I want browser zoom as a whole, not just text

Comment: You can't control that, it's browser functionality (AFAIK).

Comment: We can. Check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VAvkL/)

Comment: Unless in this solution in FF, the elements are getting hidden when zoomOut